# Does CSS Sprite use background position?

Tags: css

I have been meaning to look and learn CSS sprites and noticed Asos.com did something strange with their social icons at the footer of their page.

Their 7 social icons are pulled from the same image, is this an official use of CSS sprites?

```
<div class="scd-content-social">
<h5>Get more ASOS on:</h5>
<ul>
    <li class="fb"><a href="https://facebook.com/ASOS" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-15850b13-e42b9231"><span></span><strong>Facebook <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="tw"><a href="https://twitter.com/ASOS_Menswear" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-910b744c-512d53c7"><span></span><strong>Twitter <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="gp"><a href="https://plus.google.com/+ASOS" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-cd4fa4d5-3ad09aa1"><span></span><strong>Google + <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="pn"><a href="http://uk.pinterest.com/asos/" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-cd4fa4d5-27b4fffa"><span></span><strong>Pinterest <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="in"><a href="http://instagram.com/asos_menswear" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-910b744c-4c04a8f6"><span></span><strong>Instagram <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="yt"><a href="https://youtube.com/asosmenswear" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-6072ab01-c56c7ff"><span></span><strong>YouTube <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
    <li class="tb"><a href="http://asosmenswear.tumblr.com/" target="_blank" data-di-id="di-id-6072ab01-a5291fd9"><span></span><strong>Tumblr <em>›</em></strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a post for backlinks, but yes, CSS sprites use `background-position` to determine what part of an image is shown.

Here's a basic example of how a spritesheet works in CSS, using [a random spritesheet of Pokemon I found on Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0b7R.png).  An example of a spritesheet in action on the real web can be found [on Google itself](https://www.google.ca/images/nav_logo242.png).

```css
div.spritesheet {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0b7R.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* The spritesheet has 36 images, repeated 6x6 */
  background-size: calc(6 * 36);
}

div.spritesheet[data-id="pikachu"] {
  /* Pikachu is 0 rows from the left 1 row from the top */
  background-position: 0 calc(-1 * 64px);
}

div.spritesheet[data-id="electrode"] {
  /* Electrode is 1 row from the left 2 rows from the top */
  background-position: calc(-1 * 64px) calc(-2 * 64px);
}
```

```html
Vulpix?:
<div class="spritesheet"></div>

Pikachu:
<div class="spritesheet" data-id="pikachu"></div>

Electrode:
<div class="spritesheet" data-id="electrode"></div>
```

I don't know much about Pokemon, but this is a basic implementation of using one file to store multiple images, and using `background-position` to set which image is visible.

If you're talking about `data-di-id="di-id-6072ab01-a5291fd9"` (whatever this means), this doesn't mean anything in CSS or HTML.  It's just a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) that a sprite builder likely gave them as output, since writing non-square CSS spritesheets and keeping them updated can be irritating.

Comment: Is there a special reason other than demo to use calc() over pixels?

Comment: @Pangloss It makes it easier to adjust in the future if more sprites are added.  For example, if another row was added to the spritesheet, all pixel values would have to be manually recalculated.  Using `calc` is just easier in my opinion, but both methods work!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is very creative!